# Does UEFI save settings to CMOS

Tags: bios, uefi

I'm struggling to find out whether or not UEFI uses CMOS to store its settings or not. I'm trying to comprehend the difference between BIOS and UEFI better, I know its faster and can contain more information compared to the 16 bit BIOS previously used. It supports broader range of hardware & chipsets as well as better drivers for these devices. It supports HDD beyond 2TB, it gives you secure boot as well as better support for PXE and HTTP boot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm trying to comprehend the difference between BIOS and UEFI better,
>   I know its faster and can contain more information compared to the 16 bit 
>   BIOS previously used.

A lot depends on what you mean with *faster*:
It will not make your PC faster.
It is likely to have shorter boot times (from power up to past POST).
It is not even close to some firmwares like coreboot.

> It supports broader range of hardware & chipsets as well as better drivers
>   for these devices.

I disagree. a modern EFI firmware will support modern equipment, but a modern BIOS firmware would do the same.

> It supports HDD beyond 2TB,

Correct. But failing to support >2TiB is a limitation from the past. The origin of that was the lack of proper specifications for BIOS functions and the implementation of IDE/ATA disks.  That lead to all sorts of maximum disk size problems, and the 2TiB for 512 byte/sector disks limit is just the lastest. Any up to date BIOS firmware which recognises 4K/AF disks should do fine with MBR formatted disks up to 16TiB.

> it gives you secure boot

It does. Not secure anymore though now that the keys have leaked.

> as well as better support for PXE and HTTP boot.

PXE boot is ancient. BIOS firmware also supported external option ROMs and thus could PXE boot.

The big advantage to EFI is that it is well specified. No reverse engineering from IBMs PC, no guessing at 'this seems what most PCs do, lets do the same'. EFI is nicely documented. You know precisely what you must do when you code the EFI firmware and this means fewer incompatabilities<sup>*1</sup>.

*2. Booting from the /boot/bootX64.EFI file should work on all PCs<sup>*3</sup>. Moving a disk from one PCs to another, or even to a VM or a Mac should be much easier.  

-->

> I'm struggling to find out whether or not UEFI uses CMOS to store its
>   settings or not.

Yes and no.

Classic setups on PCs used a simple firmware called BIOS and a battery backed  memory often refereed to as CSMOS. (Though [CMOS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CMOS) realy is a manufacturing method and not a name for volatile memory). This memory was backed by a battery and this means that it would not retain its information after the battery ran out.

Many other systems (e.g. Sun Sparc, alfa based systems, old Macs, ....) used Nonvolatile memory. No battery is needed to maintain its data. [U]EFI also used NV. So depending on what you wanted to ask:

1. Yes, it also stores information somewhere on the motherboard,
2. No. It is not quite the same.

---

<sup>*1</sup>: Or shoud I say, though **should** mean fewer incompatabilities. :)

Comment: Thank you for taking the time and being on point. This clarified a lot for me I'll continue to read up on UEFI.

Comment: To clarify: NVRAM really only means it’s non-volatile. It doesn’t refer to a specific technology like NAND flash or whatever.

Answer (score 0):

No, UEFI does not store is settings under/in the same area as the old BIOS.

It has its separate sequestered area of on-board flash storage.